# Present TabBarController from another ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, viewcontroller, xcode6

I have storyboard with
SingleViewController -> TabBarController (which have 3 connected tabs)

How i can properly present it from SingleViewController ?
Currently i use code below, but it shows black screen with empty tab bar

```
class IndexTabController:UITabBarController
...
let vc = IndexTabController()
self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your are creating a new instance instead of showing the tab bar controller you configured in the storyboard.

Easiest way to present the tab controller you configured in the storyboard is to define a segue in the storyboard.